# Feedback on simple authorisation system design

Tags: design, node.js, mongodb, authorization, mongoose

I'm writing a fairly simple authentication/authorisation api for an intranet application we are developing.

It's my first roles based authorisation system and its a good opportunity for a first timer because it is located on a Windows VPS that is isolated to the internal corporate network with no internet access at all, so any mistakes I make won't have any huge consequences.

That said, I still want to do it right.

So I wanted to know if my method below is on the right track and welcome any suggestions for improvement you guys might have.

#### Notes:

- I'm using the MEAN stack as it fits the business case nicely.
- I have **bolded** the points that I am concerned about or not so sure they are the best way of doing things.
- In case I am using the wrong terminology for some things I have included my definitions below so you know what I'm trying to say.
- ***Definitions***:

  - Site-level permissions: The specific states/pages a user has access to
  - Domain: in this context is the specific data collections the user has access to.

    - This access is persistent across pages so there's nothing like User has access to Domains X and Y on Page A and Domains W and Z on Page B. If a User has access to Domains X and Y, then this is used for all site-level states.

Here's what I'm thinking:

## Account Creation

1. User account is created
2. Using Active Directory (AD), we determine site-level permissions and domain-specific permissions

   - Store User Identifier and site-level permissions in DB

## Login

1. The authentication api verifies Identity and returns an JSON web token (JWT)
2. **The identity token is then used to get another token specifically for *authorisation***. The payload of the JWT contains the role specific site-level and domain-level permissions for that user.
3. Auth Token is returned to the Client and checked in `$routeChangeStart` event of `ui-router`
4. Angular then sets the appropriate state for the requested view based on the permissions.

---

#### Specific Questions for the programmers.stackexchange gurus:

- Does this look like an ok way to implement an Authorisation system?
- Given that I have access to Active Directory am I overcomplicating this by storing permissions in a Roles collection in Mongo?
- Are there any rookie flaws in this design that I should correct/ do more reading on?

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I really appreciate any feedback you might have.